# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXXX is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reactjs, commonjs

I got a very weird bug which I've spent a couple of hours to solve but that just didn't work. The code is shown below:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>TEST</div>
      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

This works fine but if I added something like `var XXX = require('XXX')`. It will say, `Uncaught ReferenceError: Post is not defined`, which doesn't make sense to me at all. What's more interesting is that if you create your react component like the following approach:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass(/*...*/);
```

This will not work if you have require module in front unless you remove the `var` and it works magically.

So, I don't know if that's a problem of my rails project or something goes wrong with ES6.

Does anyone have similar problem before?

Comment: How are you using commonjs? Browserify?

Comment: Yes, we used Browserify.

Comment: From one of the articles I read(https://medium.com/technically-speaking/rails-react-browserify-e315001d5974#.6n8aidtct), it says, 
React will look for our components in the global scope. Is it true? This kinda explains why the errors is gone when I removed the 'var' keyword.
If that's the case, is there a way to make the class global? (This doesn't sound right to me.)

Comment: Can we see more code? It kind of sounds like you're not exporting your components properly. Of course putting them on the global namespace will work, but if you're using browserify then normal require + module.exports will work with `var`